# How to pass data from a GraphQL query onto a programmatically generated page?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am a beginner with GraphQL and I'm having trouble accessing the data from my GraphQL query. I have been able to console log the data, which shows that the query is working but when I try to access it I get the error message "Cannot read property 'page_name' of undefined"

See images of variations I have tried:

```
https://i.ibb.co/6JS20K5/Graph-QL-1.png
https://i.ibb.co/wMq1V6g/Graph-QL-2.png
https://i.ibb.co/MN5g5Pk/Graph-QL-3.png
```

I can see my data in the console when I use: 
    console.log(data.allPagesJson.edges)

My understanding is that, in order to access the exact data I need, I should use:

```
console.log(data.allPagesJson.edges.node.page_name)
```

However, this now gives me the error message "Cannot read property 'page_name' of undefined". The reason for this seems to be that "node" is undefined but I'm not sure why...

## This is my pages template:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"


export default ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data.allPagesJson.edges.node.page_name)
  return (

      <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>

  )
}

export const query = graphql`
query($page_url: String!) {
  allPagesJson(filter: { page_url: { eq: $page_url } }) {
    edges{
      node{
        page_url
        page_name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

## This is my pages gatsby-node.js file:

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    return graphql(`
    {
        allPagesJson {
          edges {
            node {   
             page_url
            }
          }
        } 

      }
    `
  ).then(result => {    
      result.data.allPagesJson.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
            path: node.page_url,
            component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/product-pages.js`),
            context: {

                page_url: node.page_url,
      },
    })
  })
    })
  }
```

Comment: `edges` is an array, so you need to iterate over the array to access the properties within each array item.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out. I can access the data using:

```
<div>
        {data.allPagesJson.edges.map(({ node }) => (
            <div key={node.id}>

                <h1>{node.page_name}</h1>


            </div>
          ))}


      </div>
```